# variable $message content pass from form is not been sent

Tags: php, phpmailer

The variable in the $message is not being sent. It only sent a blank email with table form and title without variable passed from the form.  Kindly assist

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$mess = $_POST['mess'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mail = new PHPMailer();
// send from
$mail->addAddress('*****@gmail.com', 'title');
// send to 
$mail->setFrom('*****@gmail.com', 'title');
//subject
$mail->Subject = "Test email!";
$mail->isHTML(true);
$message ='

        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table >
    <tr>
        <td width="30%">Topic</td>
        <td> '.$_POST['subject'].'</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
    ';

$mail->Body = ($message);

if (!$mail->send())
    echo "wrong";
else
    echo "Mail sent";
}
?>
```

This is the form that variable are being sent from

```
<form method="post" action="$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Subject..."><br>
<input class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Email">
</form>
```

My expectation is, all variable  passed from form above to be send to email

Comment: do not use `PHP_SELF` for the form action - simply leave it blank. The input `subject` has no `type` attribute - it should be, most likely, `text` There is no field called `mess` or `email` either

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would need to alter your html a little as any form element that is to appear in the POST array must have a `name` attribute. If you expect the user to POST their email and a message then you need suitable fields for those in the form. As the form is submitting to the same page you can omit the form action - besides, `PHP_SELF` is spoofable.

```
<?php

    if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['mess'], $_POST['email'] ) ){

        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $mess = $_POST['mess'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];



        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->addAddress('*****@gmail.com', 'title');
        $mail->setFrom('*****@gmail.com', 'title');
        $mail->Subject = 'Test email!';
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        $message =sprintf('
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>email</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td width='30%'>Topic</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=2>%s</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </body>
            </html>',
            $subject,
            $mess
        );

        $mail->Body = ($message);

        if( !$mail->send() ) echo 'wrong';
        else echo 'Mail sent';
    }
?>





<form method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='subject' class='form-control' placeholder='Subject...' /><br />
    <input type='text' name='mess' class='form-control' placeholder='Message...' /><br />
    <input type='email' name='email' class='form-control' placeholder='username@example.com' /><br />
    <input class='btn btn-primary' name='submit' type='submit' value='Send Email'>
</form>
```